# How to find slope of angle bisector of two lines with slope M1 and M2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

Given two slopes(M1 and M2) of two distinct lines, is there any way to find the slope(M3) of angle bisectors of those two lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k_1$ and $k_2$ are two given slopes, then vectors of these two lines are $(1,k_1)$ and $(1,k_2)$, or in normalized form $u_1=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k_1^2}},\frac{k_1}{\sqrt{1+k_1^2}})$ and $u_2=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}},\frac{k_2}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}})$. Note that the vectors of bisectors are given by $u_1+u_2$ and $u_1-u_2$ as these are the diagonals of the rhombi determined by $u_1$, and $u_2$, and by $u_1$ and $-u_2$. So the vectors of the bisectors are:
$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}},\frac{k_1}{\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}+\frac{k_2}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}})$$ and
$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}},\frac{k_1}{\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}-\frac{k_2}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}}).$$
By scaling them we get vectors:
$$(1,\frac{k_1\sqrt{1+k_2^2}+k_2\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}+\sqrt{1+k_1^2}})\mbox{ and }(1,\frac{k_1\sqrt{1+k_2^2}-k_2\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}-\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}),$$
so the slopes of the bisectors are given by:
$$\frac{k_1\sqrt{1+k_2^2}+k_2\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}+\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}\mbox{ and }\frac{k_1\sqrt{1+k_2^2}-k_2\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}{\sqrt{1+k_2^2}-\sqrt{1+k_1^2}}.$$